# Regex - Match multiples of anything between [[[ and ]]]

Tags: php, regex

I need to match anything between [[[ and ]]] using regex. I then need to put all the values found between the brackets into an array.

Example text:

```
here is some 'test text [[[media-2 large right]]], [[[image-0 large left]]] the another token [[[image-1]]
```

From the above text I need to match the first two:

```
1, [[[media-2 large right]]]
2, [[[image-0 large left]]]
```

but not the last as it only has two [ at the end.

Answer (score 3):

A generic solution is this one:

```
\[{3}(?=.*?\]{3}(?!\]))((?:(?!\]{3}(?!\])).)*)
```

It reads

```
\[{3}         # 3 opening square brackets
(?=           # begin positive look-ahead ("followed by..."
  .*?\]{3}    #   ...3 closing brackets, anywhere ahead (*see explanation below)
  (?!\])      #   negative look-ahead: no more ] after the 3rd one
)             # end positive look-ahead
(             # begin group 1
  (?:         #   begin non-matching group (for atomic grouping)
    (?!       #     begin negative look-ahead ("not followed by"):
      \]{3}   #       ...3 closing square brackets
      (?!\])  #       negative look-ahead: no more ] after the 3rd one
    )         #     end negative look-ahead
    .         #     the next character is valid, match it
  )           #   end non-matching group
)             # end group 1 (will contain the wanted substring)
```

The positive look-ahead is a safeguard clause that allows the expression to fail fast when there is no `"]]]"` in a long input string.

Once it's established that a `"]]]"` *will* follow at some point ahead in the string, the negative look-ahead makes sure that the expression correctly matches strings like this one:

```
[[[foo [some text] bar]]]
                 ^
                 +-------- most of the other solutions would stop at this point
```

This expression checks at every character whether three `]` follow or not, so in this example it would include the `" bar"`.

The `"no more ] after the 3rd one"` part of the expression makes sure that the match does not end prematurely, so that in this case:

```
[[[foo [some text]]]]
```

the match would still be `"foo [some text]"`.
Without it the expression would stop too early (`"foo bar [some text"`).

Side effect is that we do not need to actually match the `"]]]"`, since the positive look-ahead made clear that they are there. We only need to match up to them, which the negative look-ahead does nicely.

Note that you need to run the expression in "dotall" mode if your input contains newline characters.

See also: http://rubular.com/r/QFo9jHEh9d

Comment: It does break though if there is no text between `[some text]` and the `]]]`, it strips the trailing `]` on `some text`

Comment: @sixeightzero Thanks. Though I must say bfrohs' solution is great as well.

Comment: Thanks - Really appreciate the time you've taken and to breakdown the regex for me. Both this and bfrohs solutions work for me.

Answer (score 2):

This checks for:

1. `[[[`
2. Followed by:

   1. Anything but `]` *-or-*
   2. One to two `]` that are not followed by `]`
3. Followed by `]]]`

```
preg_match_all('/\[\[\[(?:(?:[^\]]*|]{1,2}(?!]))*)]]]/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

This regex has the benefit of matching `]` inside of the triple-bracket wrapper (e.g. `[[[foo]bar]]]`.

***Note:** `]` does not need to be escaped, except inside character classes.*

Answer (score 1):

A safer solution:

```
\[{3}[^\]]+?\]{3}
```

Comment: `[[[foo]bar]]]` would not be matched.

Answer (score 0):

I think this works:

```
\[\[\[(.*)\]\]\]
```

But it's probably the newb way to do it :)

Comment: That seems to match everything rather than separate them out/group then. 
i.e. some text [[[media-2 large right]]] and more plain text [[[image-0 large left]]] blah blah

It matches: [[[media-2 large right]]] and more plain text [[[image-0 large left]]]

Comment: It seems to work from my tests at http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ but I am no regExpert...

Answer (score 0):

If your string will always follow that format, `subject`, `size`, `position`, you can use this:

```
$string = "here is some 'test text [[[media-2 right]]], [[[image-0]]] the another [[[image-1 left large]]] and token [[[image-1]]";

preg_match_all('/[\[]{3}(.*?)(.*?)?(.*?)?[\]]{3}/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Sometimes the size, position aren't needed/provided